# Как сделать запрос в столбец при условии?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица **dle_post**, нужно вставить в столбец **xfields** значение при условии, что в **category** есть значение **"1"**. Как организовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через `IF` (http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Control_flow_functions.html)

```
Переменная = какоеToЗначение


UPDATE  dle_post
SET     xfields = IF(category = 1, Переменная, xfields)
/* WHERE   id = 100 */
```

через `CASE` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

```
Переменная = какоеToЗначение

UPDATE  dle_post
SET     xfields = CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN Переменная ELSE xfields END
/* WHERE   id = 100 */
```